# fullcalendar - daily limit of events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, fullcalendar, limit

Is it possible to set a limit of events in fullcalendar for each day? 
 I had no problem to set a limit of displayed events (already done that), but I have no idea how to do that for existing events.

Answer (score 0):

OK, somehow I've managed to deal with creation of too many events.

First, you have to count events occured in one particular day and check whether new one is going to pass your limit, so in your model:

```
def daily_events_limit(date)
    date.each do |d|
        if Event.where('start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?', d, d).count > 4
            break false
        end
    true
end
```

Then, in your controller:

```
def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    if (!@event.daily_events_limit(@event.start_date..@event.end_date) )
        redirect_to @event, notice: 'You cannot get free day in selected period of time.'
    else
        ...
    end
end
```

In this case you cannot make new event which will start, end or pass a date with already 5 events.

I don't know if it is an elegant way do deal with this problem, but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually logic preventing the creation / deletion / update of a class object should happen in the Model. This lets you make sure your rule is always checked, not just that one instance in that one controller. You can use validation to do this:

In Model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    validate :validate_event_limit

    private

    def validate_event_limit
        if Event.where(start_date: self.start_date.beginning_of_day..self.start_date.end_of_day).count > 4
            errors[:base] << "You cannot get free day in selected period of time."
        end
    end
end
```

In Controller:

```
def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    if @event.save
        ...
    else
        redirect_to @event, notice: @event.errors.full_messages
    end
end
```

This will stop a 5th Event from being created on a day. Because you used validation, you can use the same logic to check an update that might move an Event from one day to another as well:

```
def update
    if @event.update(event_params)
        ...
    else
        redirect_to @event, notice: @event.errors.full_messages
    end
end
```